# "Data collected helps scientists" or "data that is collected helps scientists"

Tags: verbs

> The real-time data collected helps scientists better understand what’s
>   happening to rivers and estuaries around the world.

Should it be,

> "The real-time data **that is** collected..."?

What is the rule regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule called Reduced Relative Clause allowing you to delete the relative pronoun and the verb *to be* when the following lexical (main) verb is in the participial (either past or present participial) form.

Comment: P.s. While it's true that 'collected..' is a post-modifing participial clause (not a relative clause), the term 'reduced relative clause' is still helpful and easier for learners to understand.